# Flash message not showing up on page redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a nodejs server and mysql database. After a successful adding of new rows I am populating the flash message success variable like this:

```
req.flash('success','New parts has been added to the database')
```

I am also setting up a flash message middleware like this:

//Setup flash middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.error=req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success=req.flash("success");
    next()
})
```

I thought that populating `res.locals` will allow me to retrieve the variable in all of my ejs templates without having to send it to the template manually myself:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home",{success:req.flash('success')})
})
```

I have tried doing both but I still see no flash message in my template:

```
<% if(success && success.length >0){ %>
<div class="flash">
  <div class="color red"></div>
  <span class="text"> <p><%=success%></p></span>
  <div class="close">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Does `success` have a length when the page renders? It might need to be `locals.success`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used flash for Node.JS but what if you create an intermediary route like '/redirect' that sets the flash success message and then immediately redirects back to your root route?

```
app.get('/redirect', function(req, res){
  req.flash('success','New parts has been added to the database')
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

And then update your view to just check for success

```
<% if(success){ %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was doing `console.log(req.flash())` which was erasing the faslh variable